# Jenkins: Automated job configuration using Seed Jobs and Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, seed

I am trying to understand how to best deploy an instance of Jenkins, complete with plugins, users and jobs using Chef. I am currently using the [Chef Jenkins Supermarket cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins).

I am attempting to achieve automated deployment of our Pipelines as part of the project. From what I have gathered, the best way to go about this is to have Chef configure a seed job in Jenkins initial setup and configuration.

The seed job should specify, among other things, the git repository from which to find and use a Jenkinsfile for a given job. I've found [this resource by Daniel Spilker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL) to be helpful in explaining seed jobs.

So the seed Jenkins job would be run, which would then generate the Jenkins job we have just scripted with it (in this case the seed job would be to pull the Jenkinsfile from source control and configure a new Jenkins job (our pipeline), with the details of the Jenkinsfile).

Am I understanding this correctly as the proper way to not only automate Jenkins job configuration, but also as the proper way to always have an up to date job configuration for any given job in the event the job configuration were to change?

If we used a seed job to setup our pipeline, what are some possible solutions to having the initial seed job run automatically once Jenkins is fully configured by Chef?

As for job configuration changes that may occur over time, would we need to setup the seed job to poll source control for any changes in the Jenkinsfile periodically in the event the Jenkinsfile has been modified? (It may be helpful to note that we are currently using BitBucket for source control).

Just getting started with pipeline as code. Thanks to everybody in advance for their patience and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I've mentioned this a bit in your other questions, but the least painful approach is to treat Jenkins as a database, not a web service. Have Chef do the basic install, but then configure the initial bits by hand. For DR, rely on your backups rather than Chef.

Comment: Thanks for your answer coderanger. So your initial thoughts are to just configure Java, Jenkins, Jenkins plugins, Jenkins Admin User, and to leave all job configuration as a manual process after chef has deployed Jenkins and use the web UI to set it up? Also, jw what exactly are you referring to with 'DR'?

Comment: DR = Disaster Recovery.  Also, using chef for the jenkins job configuration can make for really long chef runs.

Comment: I disagree. Jenkins should be installed completely automated and reproducible. You see my result in [this cookbook](https://github.com/typo3-cookbooks/site-chefcitypo3org).

Comment: After looking at your cookbook @StephenKing, it seems very similar to the setup I am trying to achieve. Am I correct in the assumptions I've made in my initial post as far as using chef to create the seed job on the Jenkins instance which in turn pulls the Jenkinsfile job configuration from SCM to configure the desired job?